# HtmlUnit css not applied properly

Tags: java, css, htmlunit

I try to save the google page using HtmlUnit. But I can't get proper UI. When I check the saved page codes style tags are empty.

My code is here.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("/home/user1/Documents/Aaa")); 
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(5000);
    System.out.println("******************loaded**********************************");
    try {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com");
        page.save(new File("/home/user1/Documents/Aaa/index.html"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("******************catch***********************************");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient.close();
    System.out.println("******************finished********************************");
}
```

And my page looks like

[image]

Console logs

```
Dec 10, 2016 3:47:45 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Dec 10, 2016 3:47:46 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter runtimeError
SEVERE: runtimeError: message=[TypeError: object is not iterable] sourceName=[https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.igGBAtxEWN0.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AAiUPF6wAOL_ISBuIRxBasDAoA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGjQTdwqicso-l4vNE-7GeAqTtjtw] line=[10] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
Dec 10, 2016 3:47:46 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=RtZLWL3cDsmL8QeW4Yb4AQ' [1:14018] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Dec 10, 2016 3:47:46 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler error
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=RtZLWL3cDsmL8QeW4Yb4AQ' [1:14042] Error in expression. (Invalid token " ". Was expecting one of: <NUMBER>, "inherit", <IDENT>, <STRING>, <HASH>, <EMS>, <EXS>, <LENGTH_PX>, <LENGTH_CM>, <LENGTH_MM>, <LENGTH_IN>, <LENGTH_PT>, <LENGTH_PC>, <ANGLE_DEG>, <ANGLE_RAD>, <ANGLE_GRAD>, <TIME_MS>, <TIME_S>, <FREQ_HZ>, <FREQ_KHZ>, <RESOLUTION_DPI>, <RESOLUTION_DPCM>, <PERCENTAGE>, <DIMENSION>, <URI>, <FUNCTION>, "progid:".)
Dec 10, 2016 3:47:46 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[551] column=[0] lineSource=[null] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.igGBAtxEWN0.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AAiUPF6wAOL_ISBuIRxBasDAoA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGjQTdwqicso-l4vNE-7GeAqTtjtw] message=[TypeError: Cannot read property "Kf" from undefined (https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.igGBAtxEWN0.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AAiUPF6wAOL_ISBuIRxBasDAoA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGjQTdwqicso-l4vNE-7GeAqTtjtw#551)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "Kf" from undefined (https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.igGBAtxEWN0.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AAiUPF6wAOL_ISBuIRxBasDAoA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGjQTdwqicso-l4vNE-7GeAqTtjtw#551)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:921)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:852)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(InteractivePage.java:216)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:322)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:206)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.dispatchEvent(Window.java:2033)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window$2$1.run(Window.java:2119)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window$2.execute(Window.java:2124)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:966)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:101)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:916)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:852)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(InteractivePage.java:216)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:322)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:191)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$2.run(DomElement.java:1190)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1195)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1163)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage.setFocusedElement(InteractivePage.java:100)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage.setFocusedElement(InteractivePage.java:66)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlElement.detach(HtmlElement.java:1254)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.remove(DomNode.java:1132)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode.replace(DomNode.java:1210)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.dom.Node.replaceChild(Node.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeArray.iterativeMethod(NativeArray.java:1694)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.NativeArray.execIdCall(NativeArray.java:405)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2575)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:321)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:94)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:252)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:794)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:906)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:803)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:779)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:975)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:238)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:966)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$500(JavaScriptEngine.java:101)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:916)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:852)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.InteractivePage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(InteractivePage.java:216)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:52)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:426)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:157)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "Kf" from undefined (https://www.google.co.in/xjs/_/js/k=xjs.s.en.igGBAtxEWN0.O/m=sx,c,sb,cdos,cr,elog,hsm,jsa,r,qsm,j,p,d,csi/am=AAiUPF6wAOL_ISBuIRxBasDAoA/rt=j/d=1/t=zcms/rs=ACT90oGjQTdwqicso-l4vNE-7GeAqTtjtw#551)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
```

Any idea for this case?

**Edited**:
   I think that error is parsing when the CSS3 filter property. In the google page code like this.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#4387fd,endColorstr=#4683ea,GradientType=1)
```

In this filter has a colon and progrid has a colon. So this leads to CSS Parsing error. Any solution for this?

Comment: any console message to show?

Comment: I think you want to display the ``index.html`` rather the webClient...and try to comment ``webClient.close();``...

Comment: when comment this line webClient.close() also same result

Comment: you have ``Exception invoking constructor``...

Comment: yeah but i set the option 
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

Comment: From the layout it seems like the browser version was not applied. Try to set `webClient.getBrowserVersion().setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");` after constructor, does it change the output?

Comment: I updated the user agent. But output is same view. Again and get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

At first:

```
WARNING: CSS error: 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=hyxFWPuPJMyL8QfigajQCw'
```

This is a warning, means more or less that the css parser does not like one of the given css rules. This has not real impact because this might lead to some missing format information if the js code on the page ask a html element for the style.

Second

```
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```

These two calls are no configuration options - doing these calls at the given place is meaningless.

But both are only minor things, the only real problem you have is the

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking constructor
```

exception. This usually stops the js processing for the page (but not in your case because you have set ThrowExceptionOnScriptError to false).

To analyze the problem we need at least the stack trace of the exception that was thrown by the constructor. Usually this stack trace is also part of the log.

But maybe there is a simpler solution. You have not provided any information about the HtmlUnit version you are using. I like to suggest to use the latest available SNAPSHOT build (you can find some info how to get at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingLatestCode.html). I did a quick test with the latest htmlunit code and was able to get the page without any exception.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File("c://temp/htmlunit/aa")); 
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(5000);
    System.out.println("******************loaded**********************************");
    try {
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(1000);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
        page.save(new File("c://temp/htmlunit/aa/index.html"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("******************catch***********************************");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient.close();
    System.out.println("******************finished********************************");
}
```

Comment: Hey I updated HtmlUnit to 2.23 latest version. But I still got the progrid: Exception and also CSS not applied. And I update console logs for the updated version.

Comment: (1) My suggestion was to update to the latest snapshot....
(2)Again the ccs thing is a warning....
(3)And finally com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property is a problem. This means that (at least parts) of the script on the page is not working. If you still have this problem with the latest SNAPSHOT version of HtmlUnit you have to open an issue. But fist have a look at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html.

Comment: Another possible problem might the dumped page. This page still contains some links to your local file system and some to the internet. Maybe one of these links is broken.